# Fill an Excel table column with foreign key from another table

Tags: excel, key, fill

I have 2 tables in Excel, table1 and table 2. Table1 has only 1 column for the primary keys and table2 has 2 columns, 1 for the primary keys and a second that should use random foreign keys from table1 column 1. For now column2 of table2 is all nulls so I should fill it with random foreign keys from table1 column1. Any ideas how I should do it? I use MS Excel 2016

[image]

Comment: Please add your spredsheets and table to the post (you can add them as images)

Comment: done, I want to populate column2 of table2 with random foreign keys from table1's column1